# Generate and Control JMenu Radio Buttons Using An Enum

Tags: java, swing, enum, awt

Put together a `RadioMenu` class that can use a Enum to generate a Single-Selection Radio Button Menu. My main question is about whether there's a way to remove the need to pass in the Class of the Enum to the `generateButtonsFromEnum()` method. Otherwise, would appreciate any general pointers on ways to improve this system since I'm still pretty new when it comes to AWT/Swing features.

**RadioMenu**

```
package tools;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;

public class RadioMenu<E extends Enum<E>> extends JMenu {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  
  private E currentState;
  private JRadioButtonMenuItem selectedRadioButton;
  
  private HashMap<E, JRadioButtonMenuItem> stateMap;
  
  public RadioMenu() {
    stateMap = new HashMap<E, JRadioButtonMenuItem>();
  }
  
  public RadioMenu(String name) {
    super(name);
    stateMap = new HashMap<E, JRadioButtonMenuItem>();
  }
  
  public void addRadioButton(E enumValue, JRadioButtonMenuItem radioButton) {
    //Set default to first added button
    if(stateMap.isEmpty()) {
      currentState = enumValue;
      radioButton.setSelected(true);
      selectedRadioButton = radioButton;
    }
    
    add(radioButton);
    stateMap.put(enumValue, radioButton);
    radioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setState(enumValue);
      }
    });
  }
  
  public void generateButtonsFromEnum(Class<E> enumType) {
    for(E enumValue : enumType.getEnumConstants()) {
      addRadioButton(enumValue, new JRadioButtonMenuItem(enumValue.toString()));
    }
  }
  
  public E getState() {
    return currentState;
  }
  
  public void setState(E newState) {
    currentState = newState;
    selectedRadioButton.setSelected(false);
    
    selectedRadioButton = stateMap.get(newState);
    selectedRadioButton.setSelected(true);
  }
}
```

**RadioMenuTest**

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import tools.RadioMenu;

public class RadioMenuTest implements Runnable {

  public enum RadioOptions {
    Forward, Backward, Left, Right
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new RadioMenuTest());
  }
  
  @Override
  public void run() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("RadioMenu Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
    
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    
    RadioMenu<RadioOptions> optionsMenu = new RadioMenu<RadioOptions>("Options");
    optionsMenu.generateButtonsFromEnum(RadioOptions.class);
    fileMenu.add(optionsMenu);
    
    return menuBar;
  }
}
```

Comment: may i ask if you are allowed to use `RadioOptions[] values = RadioOptions.values();` ? doing so you could directly add all possible values (i don't know your assets).

Comment: Doing so would result in the following lines int the `main` method:  `optionsMenu.generateButtonsFromEnum(RadioOptions.values());`

Comment: it is not possible to know the **`class T`** of the **`type T`** at compile time. hence you have to provide either the **class T** (as you did) or you provide one (or more) **instance(s)** of T as suggested by `enum.values()`

Comment: @MartinFrank Ah, figured that was the case but nice to hear confirmation. Yeah, if the method is going to require a parameter no matter what it would make more sense to just pass the Enum values directly huh? Was just hoping there might be a way to avoid a parameter since the generic would be referencing the Enum anyways and it's members should be static if I recall correctly.

Comment: very nice code at all

Answer (score 2):

### dependency injection

with the feedback from your comments i would provide those `<T extends Enum<T>>` that you want to use already in your constructor. That would remove the *not-so-handy* method `generateButtonsFromEnum`.

```
public enum RadioOptions {Forward, Backward, Left, Right}
RadioMenu<RadioOptions> optionsMenu = new RadioMenu<>(RadioOptions.values());
optionsMenu.setText("Options")
```

doing so it would also let you create a **reduced** menu if you don't want to use all enum values:

```
public enum RadioOptions {Forward, Backward, Left, Right}
RadioOptions[] leftRight = {RadioOptions.Left, RadioOptions.Right} 
RadioMenu<RadioOptions> optionsMenu = new RadioMenu<>(leftRight);
optionsMenu.setText("Options")
```

Such an constructor you would provide an instance of T (as suggested in the comments).

### Note

have a look at [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) a specialized map for storing/accessings Enums.

Comment: Hit a snag with `EnumMap` where it requires the Class in the constructor (but I still like it, thanks for the tip). As a result, ended up with a compromise based on this advise where I pass the Class to the constructor and keep a `generateButtons()` method with a `generateButtons(E[] enumValues)` overload variant for generating using a array to keep the flexibility of generating using a subset. Opted to keep a `generateButtons()` method because I prefer that being explicitly executed instead of assumed behavior.

Comment: you made some good points =) a Review is very valuable to those who want to improve their skills and very rarely there is a plain *right/wrong* answer - thanks for sharing your thoughts!